# Material UI - remove border from one of the textfields

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, border

I'm trying to make an input with an icon on the left. something like this:

[image]

I've already created the input. my plan is to add the input and icon in a grid. remove input's border and add it to the grid container.

I'm not able to remove the border. I've tried using the spread operator but I was getting errors.

there are other inputs using the same styles and they need the border.

How can I remove border for this input ?

```
const useStylesCustom = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    border: '1px solid #e2e2e1',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    borderRadius: 2,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['border-color', 'box-shadow']),
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
    },
    '&$focused': {
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      borderColor: '#DFDFDF',
    },
    '&$error': {
      borderColor: theme.palette.error.main,
    },
  },
  focused: {},
  error: {},
}));

<Grid container>
  <Grid xs={2} style={{ alignSelf: 'center', textAlign: 'center' }} item>
    <img src="/img/usa_flag.svg" height="25" />
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={10}>
    <TextField
      fullWidth
      label='Phone number'
      variant='filled'
      value={lastName}
      style={{ border: '0' }}
      InputProps={{ classes, disableUnderline: true }}
      onChange={(e) => setLastName(e.target.value)}
    />
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the variant and no border will be displayed:

```
    <Grid container style={{border: "1px solid black"}}>
  <Grid xs={2} style={{ alignSelf: 'center', textAlign: 'center' }} item>
    <img src="/img/usa_flag.svg" height="25" />
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={10}>
    <TextField
      fullWidth
      label='Phone number'
      value={"lastName"}
      style={{ border: '0' }}
      InputProps={{ classes, disableUnderline: true }}
      
    />
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Here is a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/m43tj?file=/demo.js:359-769).